# Copying a MongoDB record for record

Tags: mongodb

We have a MongoDB sitting at 600GB. We've deleted a lot of documents, and in the hopes of shrinking it, we repaired it onto a 2TB drive.

It ran for hours, eventually running out of the 2TB space. When I looked at the repair directory, it had created way more files than the original database??

Anyway, I'm trying to look for alternative options. My first thought was to create a new MongoDB, and copy each row from the old to the new. Is it possible to do this, and what's the fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of success in copying database using the db.copyDatabase command:

link to mongodb [copyDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/)

I have also used MongoVUE, which is a software that makes it easy to copy databases from one location to another - [MonogoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/) (which is jus ta graphical interface on top of monogo).

If you have no luck with copyDatabase, I can suggest you try to dump and restore the database to an external file, something like [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump) or [lvcreate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/)

Here is a full read on backup and restore which should allow you to copy the database easily: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/

Comment: I was wondering, does the copyDatabase function copy record for record, effectively compacting the database by removing unused space?

Comment: copyDatabase will copy your collections, install mongoVUE, which makes it very easy to copy and select which collections you'd like to copy. In general it's super simple and you can even provide a list of collections if you wish to..What is the point you're trying to reach however?

Comment: I wanted to repair the database just to recover some space, but the repair isn't finishing.

Comment: Why repair? what's taking space?

Comment: We've deleted about half of the documents from the database. As I understand it, MongoDB will reuse the space once more documents are added, but we wanted to reclaim the space immediately by repairing it on a scheduled maintenance basis.

Comment: what version of mongo are you running?

Comment: @drminaar That's a horrible idea. For a repair, you should always calculate at least the same amount of disk space you use at the moment. Also, a repair is nothing to mitigate bad system planning. If the disk space MongoDB needs at peak times might be needed elsewhere on other times, you need to increase your disk space for the sole reason that both events might occur the same time.